# Add values from a list of objects to another list of different objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have this scenario

```
class A
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public string val3 { get; set; }
    public string val4 { get; set; }
    public string val5 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public string val3 { get; set; }
}

List<A> lista = new List<A>(); //10 items

List<B> listb = new List<B>(); //400 items
```

I want to store in `A`, the values of `B` that match the `id` field (`val2` and `val3` of `B` into `val2` and `val3` of `A`, by `id`) , how can I do this?

Comment: Create `new A()` and copy properties from `B`, and add this new object instead of `B`.

Comment: Your class design is pretty odd. Asuming those fields are actually of the same type in practice, you may want to use a nested array. Or maybe a Tupel instead of a custom class. If it is not that ideal, Linq is pretty much the prefered way,

Answer (score 1):

### Creating new objects

You can use LINQ/[Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the B's into A's and add them with [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
lista.AddRange
(
    listb.Select
    (
        b => new A 
        { 
            id   = b.id, 
            val2 = b.val2, 
            val3 = b.val3 
        } 
    )
);
```

### Putting both types of objects in the same list

Or, if you literally want to store both A's and B's in the same list, you can set up an inheritance relationship:

```
class B
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public string val3 { get; set; }
}

class A : B
{
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val4 { get; set; }
    public string val5 { get; set; }
}

var listb = new List<B>();
```

Now your list can store both A and B, because A is a specialization of B. So you can do this:

```
listb.AddRange(lista);
```

### Updating in place

If you want to keep the original objects in `lista` and just want to update the matching properties, you should probably use a loop. It's possible to do it with LINQ if you really want, but it's really not "meant" for updating things in place.

It does make things a little easier to store your As in a dictionary, since you get the lookup ability. A dictionary uses a hash table internally so you will also get better performance than a scan. Because the dictionary only contains references, the objects in the original list will get updated too.

```
var dictionarya = lista.ToDictionary
(
    item => item.id,
    item => item
);
foreach (var b in listb)
{
    A a;
    if (dictionarya.TryGetValue(b.id, out a))
    {
        a.val2 = b.val2;
        a.val3 = b.val3;
    }
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't check if the `id`s match.

Comment: Revised with an additional answer for id-matching update.

Answer (score 1):

The following LINQ query should get you there:

```
lista.AddRange(from b in listb
               let a = new A { id = b.id, val2 = b.val2, val3 = b.val3}
               where lista.Any(x => x.id == a.id)
               select a);
```

This will select a list of all B that share an ID with a value in lista, then add the result to lista.

Comment: `lista.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == a.id) != null` can be simplified to `lista.Any(x => x.id == a.id)`

Comment: @Aominè Good catch.

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants after reading the description several times. +1

Comment: Also, it is more efficient to do `from b in listb     
            where lista.Any(x => x.id == b.id)
            select new A { id = b.id, val2 = b.val2, val3 = b.val3 };` as this means you only create the `A` objects _when you need to_ .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good job for the `Join` clause:

```
var result = lista.Join(listb,
                       a => a.id,
                       b => b.id,
                       (a, b) => 
                       new A { id = a.id, val2 = b.val2, val3 = b.val3 });
```

This will accomplish your description of "I want to store in `A`, the values of `B` that match the `id` field".

if instead, you want to accumulate the result from the `Join` clause to `lista`, then you can utilise the `AddRange` method:

```
lista.AddRange(result);
```